# Ansible escape * in regex

Tags: regex, ansible

I'm trying to use Ansible's [lineinfile module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/lineinfile_module.html) to ensure that a line beginning with a * is present in a file. However, the task fails every time with the following error

```
TASK: [nginx | Persist soft ulimit] *******************************************
failed: [aa.bb.cc.dd] => {"failed": true, "parsed": false}
BECOME-SUCCESS-xbfifannrufpkcmmfmtdigorggzvhzsx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1442590356.11-253796220854159/lineinfile", line 2210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1442590356.11-253796220854159/lineinfile", line 394, in main
    ins_aft, ins_bef, create, backup, backrefs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1442590356.11-253796220854159/lineinfile", line 208, in present
    mre = re.compile(regexp)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 190, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 244, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/xyz/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
debug1: mux_client_request_session: master session id: 2
Shared connection to aa.bb.cc.dd closed.
```

The task is as follows

```
- name: Persist soft ulimit
  lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/security/limits.conf
    regexp: "^\* soft nofile"
    line: "* soft nofile 9000"
```

Given typical escaping of regex, I'd assumed that it'd be escaped with \, but I just get the above error.

Ansible is 1.9.2

```
$ ansible --version
$ ansible 1.9.2
```

Comment: Try `regexp: "^\\* soft nofile"`. If it is processed with Python, you need to use double backslashes.

Comment: I had tried this but not noticed it was moving on successfully to the next task which had a single `\` and an almost identical task name! \\\* does indeed work.

Comment: When you need to escape regexp metachars, @WiktorStribiżew 's answer is the way to go

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One sure-fire way of escaping (most) characters is to wrap it in a character class:

```
regexp: "^[*] soft nofile"
```

Comment: This does work, as does the comment on the question, \\\*

Comment: What about escaping a character set? If I want to do `\[stanza\]` would i use single or double quotes?

Comment: @Arcsector what do you mean exactly by "escaping a character set"?

Comment: @Bohemian Ansible regex interprets character sets as something like `[abc]` - if I have, for example, an ini file stanza, normally Ansible would interpret that as a character set like `[stanzadef]`. I want to escape the character set so Ansible reads it as literal brackets. Though I think my question was answered as I tested, one must use single quotes.

Comment: @Arcsector just so we're on the same page, `[stanzadef]` (or just `[stanzdef]` - repeated chars in a character class are redundant) matches a **single** character that is either `s`, `t`, `a`, `n`, `z`, `d`, `e` or `f`. If you want to match the literal character sequence `stanza` you delete the square brackets. If you want to match a literal open square bracket, escape it `\[` (you don't need to escape a close square bracket `]`).